# Passing Input to Step Function from a manual approval step

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have a usecase where one of the task in Step Function is Manual Approval Step.
As a part of completion of this step, we want to pass some inputs which will be used by subsequent tasks.

This there a way to do it ?

I have seen passing JSON in output while completing the Manual Approval Step. Is there a way that we can read this output as input in next step ?

```
client.sendTaskSuccess(new SendTaskSuccessRequest()
    .withOutput("{\"key\": \"this is value\"}")
    .withTaskToken(getActivityTaskResult.getTaskToken()));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but your question doesn't provide enough information for a specific answer. Some general tips about input/output processing:

1. By default, the output of a state becomes the input to the next state. You can use `ResultPath` to write the output of the the Task to a new field without replacing the entire JSON payload that becomes the input to the next state.
2. If subsequent states are using `InputPath` or `Parameters`, you might be filtering the input and removing the output of the approval step. Similarly with `OutputPath`.

The doc on Input and Output Processing may be helpful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-input-output-filtering.html